# Labels length 2 should be 1 or 0

Tags: r

I have this data:

```
library(dplyr)
dframefull <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), name = c("Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", "Google"), date = c("12/8/2014 19:30:57", "26/8/2014 19:30:57", "27/8/2014 10:12:01", "27/8/2014 14:10:29", "27/8/2014 14:10:32", "27/8/2014 14:10:33", "3/9/2014 14:10:32", "14/9/2014 19:30:57"), mytext = c("out text", "text", "another", "text", "here", "other text", "text more", "out text 2"))
dframekeep <- data.frame(id = c(1), name = c("Google"), date = c("27/8/2014 14:10:32"))
```

and running this commands

```
b <- with(dframefull, 
           aggregate(list(mytext=mytext), 
                     by=list(id=id, 
                             label=factor(I(date > dframekeep$date), labels=c("before", "after")), 
                             name=name), 
                     FUN=paste))
```

And I receive this error:

```
Error in factor(I(date > dframekeep$date), labels = c("before", "after")) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 2 should be 1 or 0
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(date, dframekeep$date) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

Expected result is to keep 10 days before and 10 days after the time stamp of the second dataframe taking into considaration the seconds

```
data.frame(id = c(1,1), label = c("before", "after"), name = c("Google", "Google"), mytext = c("text another text here", "other text text more"))
  id  label   name                 mytext
1  1 before Google text another text here
2  1  after Google   other text text more
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: In your code, the `date` columns of `dframefull` and `dframekeep` are factors.  Perhaps you need to convert them to `Date` objects first?

Comment: @Benjamin I used date objects but it does not take into consideration the hour minute seconds

Comment: @Bruno updated with expected results

Comment: My apologies.  You need to make them `POSIXct` objects.  I'm submitting an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made two changes to your code. First, I used the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` argument in `data.frame`. Second, I converted your `date` columns to `POSIXct` class (date/time class).

This allows your example code to run without error.  I hope the solution in your production data is similar.

```
library(dplyr)
dframefull <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), 
                         name = c("Google", "Google", "Google", "Google", 
                                  "Google", "Google", "Google", "Google"), 
                         date = c("12/8/2014 19:30:57", "26/8/2014 19:30:57", 
                                  "27/8/2014 10:12:01", "27/8/2014 14:10:29", 
                                  "27/8/2014 14:10:32", "27/8/2014 14:10:33", 
                                  "3/9/2014 14:10:32",  "14/9/2014 19:30:57"), 
                         mytext = c("out text", "text", "another", "text", 
                                    "here", "other text", "text more", 
                                    "out text 2"),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date, 
                           format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
dframekeep <- data.frame(id = c(1), 
                         name = c("Google"), 
                         date = c("27/8/2014 14:10:32"),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
  mutate(date = as.POSIXct(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))

b <- with(dframefull, 
          aggregate(list(mytext=mytext), 
                    by=list(id=id, 
                            label=factor(I(date > dframekeep$date), labels=c("before", "after")), 
                            name=name), 
                    FUN=paste))
```

Comment: thank you very much. It is right. One more question any idea how is it possible to keep 10 days before and 10 days after the date of the second dataframe?

Comment: Try `I(date > dframekeep$date - lubridate::days(10) & date < dframekeep$date + lubridate::days(10))`

Comment: In before label it keeps the 10 days before and after. What I try is the expected output I have in the question